# Velocity Relation for Parallel Robots

Tags: kinematics, forward-kinematics, jacobian

In my course of "Advanced Robotics" with "Fundamental of Robotic Mechanical Systems" as the reference book I saw the following equation as the velocity relation for parallel manipulators such as the one depicted on the pic.

$$\mathbf{J}\mathbf{\dot{\theta}}=\mathbf{K}\mathbf{t}$$

$\mathbf{\dot{\theta}}$ is the joint rate vector and $\mathbf{t}$ is the twist.

[image]

where $\theta_{J1}$ for $1\leq J\leq 3$ is the actuator.

It was indicated there that usually the matrix $\mathbf{J}$ is a diagonal matrix referring to the borders of the work space. But the proof for this velocity relation was just given case by case. In another word there was no general proof of this equation.

So here are my questions

1. Is there a way to derive a general velocity formula for parallel manipulators ? (a formula that would show the relation between joint rates and twists).
2. Are there cases in which $\mathbf{J}$ is not a diagonal matrix ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you can write the forward kinematics equations of a parallel robot in an explicit form, you can derivate those equations and you get the formula for the velocities. This is  generally valid approach for *all* robots, but the formulae obtained are only valid for the specific structure.
2. If the jacobi matrix is diagonal it means that the motions of the robot are decoupled. i.e. if only one joint moves, only one component of the 6 (or 3 the planar case) velocities of the end effector will change. The ISOGlide type parallel structures have a diagonal jacobi matrix, as published [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226125804_Theoretical_and_Experimental_Research_on_the_Dynamics_of_a_4DOF_Isoglide_4-T3R1_Parallel_Robot). Portal or Cartesian type structures, like [this](http://machinedesign.com/site-files/machinedesign.com/files/uploads/2013/09/121213-6-Cartesian-robot-supports.jpg),  also have a diagonal jacobi matrix. [Delta robots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_robot), [Stewart platfroms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart_platform), [Scara robots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCARA) and 6 axis [puma robots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_Universal_Machine_for_Assembly) do not have a diagonal jacobi matrix.

(By looking at the schematic you attached, and not doing the math, I am not convinced that the robot you described has a diagonal jacobi matrix)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. In the case of number one I'm more interested in a solution with geometrical interpretation (Like the solution that one would find on "Geometric Fundamentals of Robotics" about the serial manipulator's velocity relation).

Comment: and in the case of the robot depicted above, the Jacobian matrix J in fact is diagonal ... you can find the proof on page 407 of Angeles "Fundamental of Robotic Mechanical Systems".

Comment: Which edition of the mentioned book?

Comment: third edition if I'm not wrong

Comment: OK, so the Jacobi matrix of the mechanism is broken into a diagonal matrix (J) and a row matrix (K).  At the end of the chapter this is further emphasized.  I would assume that this formalism can be applied for other parallel structures also. Other than singularity analysis, I do not see any advantages in this formalism.

Comment: Well having the interpretation in an invariant language such as Lie groups would always be beneficial. Especially that I'm a math student who works in robotics and I'm always more interested in these interpretations.

Comment: This is a rather subjective advantage...